# Jenkins plugin - environment variables

Tags: variables, plugins, jenkins, environment

I am using Jenkins with Testswarm and this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/testswarm-plugin) ([forked sources](https://github.com/gmoulin/jenkins-testswarm-plugin)).

I want to get a "job name" for Testswarm containing the Jenkins job name, build number and svn revision number.

Putting JOB_NAME in the configuration field does not help, the variable is not replaced by its value.

So I modified the plugin source code to get the Jenkins environment variables but all I get are "null"s.

Here is the culprit code. (in src/main/java/com/javaclimber/jenkins/testswarmplugin/TestSwarmBuilder.java from line 205)

I researched a lot concerning this functionnality and I did not find a working example for **getting** a variable.

```
public boolean perform(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    ...
EnvVars envVars = build.getEnvironment(listener);
    ...
    envVars.get("JOB_NAME")
}
```

I am not at ease in Java and I am stuck at this point.
Any idea anyone, please ?

Update: java used version
java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~10.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replacing

```
EnvVars envVars = build.getEnvironment(listener);
```

By

```
EnvVars envVars = new EnvVars();
envVars = build.getEnvironment(listener);
```

did the trick...

Comment: That makes no sense... Both code snippets should produce the same thing, except the second one creates an instance of `EnvVars` which is never used and gets discarded straight away. Any idea *why* this solved the problem?

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question and making my life easier.

Comment: @Illidanek, Jenkins pipelines appear to execute on the server, so the original post's author might be missing a variable defined for the agent (either via the server's agent definition or via the agent's OS).

Answer (score 1):

What version of Java are you using?
According to [this](http://www.codebeach.com/2008/02/get-environment-variables-in-java.html), to get an environment variable, you need to add the following:

```
String job_name = System.getenv("JOB_NAME");
```

Have you tried this instead?

Also, I'm not sure what the configuration field looks like, but did you try using `$JOB_NAME` instead of `JOB_NAME` ?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins pipelines appear to execute on the server, so the original post may be missing a variable defined for the agent (either via the server's agent definition or via the agent's OS).

I don't know the Jenkins pipeline way of obtaining the agent's environment.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over this and searched a while for a solution, so for the next user the answer: If you need the environment variables, overwrite

`public void perform(Run<?, ?> run, FilePath workspace, EnvVars env, Launcher launcher, TaskListener listener)`

instead of

`public void perform(Run<?, ?> run, FilePath workspace, Launcher launcher, TaskListener listener)`

and use the `EnvVars` from the parameters. (See also https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-29144)