# How to obtain Job parameters in a custom Jenkins Plugin?

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I am developing a custom plugin for jenkins.  You can apparently get all sorts of Job parameters using environment variables in Ant scripts but apparently those variables are not set for plugins.

Here is my code

```
@Override
public boolean perform(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) {
// This is where you 'build' the project.
// Since this is a dummy, we just say 'hello world' and call that a build.

String BUILD_NUMBER = System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER");
String BUILD_ID = System.getenv("BUILD_ID");
String BUILD_URL = System.getenv("BUILD_URL");
String NODE_NAME = System.getenv("NODE_NAME");
String JOB_NAME = System.getenv("JOB_NAME");
String BUILD_TAG = System.getenv("BUILD_TAG");
String JENKINS_URL = System.getenv("JENKINS_URL");
String EXECUTOR_NUMBER = System.getenv("EXECUTOR_NUMBER");
String JAVA_HOME = System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
String WORKSPACE = System.getenv("WORKSPACE");
String SVN_REVISION = System.getenv("SVN_REVISION");
String CVS_BRANCH = System.getenv("CVS_BRANCH");
String GIT_COMMIT = System.getenv("GIT_COMMIT");
String GIT_URL = System.getenv("GIT_URL");
String GIT_BRANCH = System.getenv("GIT_BRANCH");

listener.getLogger().println("BUILD_NUMBER = " + BUILD_NUMBER);
listener.getLogger().println("BUILD_ID = " + BUILD_ID);
listener.getLogger().println("BUILD_URL  = " + BUILD_URL);
listener.getLogger().println("NODE_NAME = " + NODE_NAME);
listener.getLogger().println("JOB_NAME = " + JOB_NAME);
listener.getLogger().println("BUILD_TAG = " + BUILD_TAG);
listener.getLogger().println("JENKINS_URL = " + JENKINS_URL);
listener.getLogger().println("EXECUTOR_NUMBER = " + EXECUTOR_NUMBER);
listener.getLogger().println("JAVA_HOME = " + JAVA_HOME);
listener.getLogger().println("WORKSPACE = " + WORKSPACE);
listener.getLogger().println("SVN_REVISION = " + SVN_REVISION);
listener.getLogger().println("CVS_BRANCH = " + CVS_BRANCH);
listener.getLogger().println("GIT_COMMIT  = " + GIT_COMMIT);
listener.getLogger().println("GIT_URL = " + GIT_URL);
listener.getLogger().println("GIT_BRANCH  = " + GIT_BRANCH);


return true;
```

}

Here is the output:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Documents and Settings\ojblass\.jenkins\jobs\Test_Job\workspace
Updating https://svnserver.com/svn/repos/a/b/c at revision '2014-07-24T08:58:28.695 -0500'
At revision 13
no change for https://svnserver.com/svn/repos/a/b/c since the previous build
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '"ant.bat && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
Buildfile: C:\Documents and Settings\ojblass\.jenkins\jobs\Test_Job\workspace\build.xml

build-subprojects:

init:

build-project:
     [echo] SecurityVulnerabilities: C:\Documents and Settings\ojblass\.jenkins\jobs\Test_Job\workspace\build.xml

build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
Results Location = \\wojblass\c$\temp publish = true
BUILD_NUMBER = null
BUILD_ID = null
BUILD_URL? = null
NODE_NAME = null
JOB_NAME = null
BUILD_TAG = null
JENKINS_URL = null
EXECUTOR_NUMBER = null
JAVA_HOME = C:\progra~1\java\jdk1.6.0_26
WORKSPACE = null
SVN_REVISION = null
CVS_BRANCH = null
GIT_COMMIT? = null
GIT_URL = null
GIT_BRANCH? = null
Finished: SUCCESS
```

As you can see all the parameters are null and I am not sure how I am supposed to get at them.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14231001/1213907

```
EnvVars envVars = new EnvVars();
envVars = build.getEnvironment(listener);
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I did search but you found my proverbial needle in a haystack!