# Accessing Jenkins-set environment variables from a Jenkins Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

If there is a Jenkins shell script build step, environment variables are set so that, for example, if you echo $WORKSPACE you see the current working directory. I am writing a custom plugin which also can execute shell commands but WORKSPACE is not set when this plugin executes.

I could see that Jenkins sets all those env variables prior to executing the shell commands the Jenkins project specifies so that they would not be already set for a custom plugin. If that is the case, it would seem like there is no way to access those env variables.

But if there is a way to obtain the values of the env variables that would be useful.

Comment: This is a problem which also bothers me. I've built an mwe: https://github.com/DaGeRe/example-no-environment Neither `System.getenv` nor `run.getEnvironment(listener)` are able to get defined environment variables. Unfortunately, I did not find any solution so far, so I would be glad if you could share a solution if you found one.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214249/jenkins-plugin-environment-variables